# Project.getConvention() method has been deprecated

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle 8.2.1 and my project shows the following errors while building but doesn't say anything about which line fails in build.gradle. How to find the problem?

```
> Configure project :
The Project.getConvention() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
The org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
The org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginConvention type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#java_convention_deprecation

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 23s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 3):

So this problem once again started happening to me. I now share what I've discovered.

To diagnose the problem I enabled gradle to give all warnings.  I did this by adding the following to the "gradle.properties" file:

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

I then ran gradle build from a terminal enabling stacktrack

```
./gradlew build -stacktrace
```

From that I could get a link to the offending gradle code.  To my surprise the the source code was from the a gradle 8.1.2 cache directory.  That surprised me because my project was configured to use gradle 8.6.  I did the following:

```
./gradlew version
```

and it confirmed that I was using gradle version 8.6.  So I then looked at how to clear the global gradle cache.  The only reliable way I found to clear it was to delete the build-cache-1 directory in my .gradle/caches directory. For windows that global cache directory was in my home user directory. If you find other "build-cache-"x directory delete all of them.  In my case I only had the build-cache-1 directory. As everyone knows, they'll automagically get rebuilt for you.

After doing that most of deprecate gradle warnings when away.  I did have a warning about BuildIdentifier.isCurrentBuild has been deprecated.  Doing a similar technique I could find where that error was occurring.  But this time I could see that it was coming from the 8.6 gradle cache.  I looked at the code and could see that its deliberately throwing this warning (nagAboutDeprecatedIsCurrentBuild()). So you can then assume it'll be fixed when the release for gradle 9.0 happens as there's nothing you can do other then by suppressing the warning if that bothers you.

Comment: Just to be thorough, I did run "./gradlew build -no-build-cache" prior to clearing the global gradle cache.  That seem to help, but I did have some issues that didn't go away until I deleted the global gradle cache.  I don't recall what those issues were! So you might have to additionally do that step too. It's not clear to me if build cache and gradle cache are associated or completely independent concepts!

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem. Deleting old caches did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First check to make sure none of your Gradle build files use `getConvention()`/`convention` anywhere.

If none of your Gradle files use the deprecated method/convention concept, then it is likely a plugin you are using that is using it. For example, if you were using the Spring Java Format Gradle plugin, it was using `getConvention()` until recently and has since been fixed in [this](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat/commit/7e97f323d96758d58ed57701c36cd2c69f9fc0fe) commit.

You will need to go through your plugins one by one (enable/disable plugin) to see which one is causing the deprecation warning. Once you have found the plugin, check their GitHub issue tracker or whatever issue tracker they use to see if someone else has raised the issue. If not, then raise it so you can help the community.

Comment: If I comment a plugin the project is not compiling at all.... Is there any easy way to find which dependency causing the problem?
These are my plugins:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.github.triplet.play'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

Answer (score 0):

Cisco answer is correct.  You most likely need to upgrade the version of one of your plugins that your project is using.  I had this same issue and I had to upgrade the plugin id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") to version 1.8.10 and the plugin id("com.android.library") to version 8.1.0 to get rid of this warning error.  At this time it's just a warning, but it will be an error in version 9 of gradle.